# Accessing aria-hidden elements with Scrapy-Playwright

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, css-selectors, playwright, playwright-python

I'm using scrapy to access a response element. Since this element is hidden, it returns an empty object.
How can I make this object visible?

This is the div class I like to access or click on it.

```
<div class="listing-content-provider-i0v7mt" data-genesis-element="CARD_HEADER_CONTAINER" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="stepstone-disclosure-6147" tabindex="0">...</div>
```

It is also possible to click on this element. However, this also seems not to work.

The code for making the div class visible.

```
    async def parse_jobs(self, response):
        meta=dict(
            playwright=True,
            playwright_include_page = True,
            playwright_page_methods = [
                #Waiting for the class 
                PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'div.listing-content-provider-i0v7mt','aria-expanded="true"'),
                # or
                PageMethod('click', 'div.listing-content-provider-i0v7mt'),
                ]
            )
```